# Bound on tail probability with knowledge of a bound on expected value

Tags: probability, inequality

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

If the random variables $X$, $Y$ satisfy:

$$E[(X-a)_+]\leq E[(Y-a)_+],\qquad \forall a\in R$$

and $\forall t>0$ we have:

$$P[Y\geq t]\leq ke^{-bt},\quad k\ge 1, b\ge 0$$

prove

$$P[X\geq t]\leq ke^{1-bt}$$

I don't have any idea on where to begin.

Comment: What does the suscript $()_+$ mean?

Comment: @leonbloy $(x)_+ = x$ if  $x\ge 0$ and $(x)_+ = 0$ if $x<0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R_a =(X-a)_+$, $S_a =(Y-a)_+$. Then both $R_a$ , $S_a$ are nonnegative [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formula_for_non-negative_random_variables)

$$\begin{align}
E[S_a]&=\int_0^\infty P[S_a\ge s] ds= \int_0^\infty P[Y\ge s+a] ds\\
 &\le \int_0^\infty k e^{-b(s+a)} ds = \frac{k}{b} e^{-b a} \tag1
\end{align}
$$

for any $a>0$. We do the same for $X$, calling $g(t)=P[X\ge t]$ (non increasing function):

$$\begin{align}
E[R_a]&=\int_0^\infty P[R_a\ge r] dr\\
&= \int_0^\infty P[X\ge r+a] dr\\
&= \int_0^\infty g(r+a) dr\\
&= \int_a^\infty g(t) dt\\
&\ge g(t)(t-a) \tag2\\
\end{align}
$$
for any $t> a$. Hence, given that $E[R_a]\le E[S_a]$, we have

$$ g(t) \le \frac{k}{b(t-a)} e^{-ab} \tag3$$

for all $0<a<t$. In particular, to get the tightest bound, we see that the RHS, regarded as function of $a$, has a minimum at $a_0 = t-1/b$. And at that point, the RHS evaluates to $ k e^{1-bt}$. Then

$$ g(t)=P[X \gt t] \le k e^{1-bt}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. Why $\int P[S_a\ge s] ds =\int P[Y\ge s+a] ds$? How did you remove $(.)_+$?

Comment: @SMA.D The integral is over $s > 0$, so $(Y-a)_+ \ge s \iff Y \ge s + a$

Comment: @SMAD The event $(Y-a)_+ \ge s$ , for $s>0$ is equivalent to $Y-a \ge s$. , so the $()_+$ operator is irrelevant here. It was essential, however, to assume that the variables $R_a$ are non-negative.